# Facebook Api Path issue

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've got the following issue with the Facebook API:

```
[Sat May 21 23:45:14.246946 2016]  
[fcgid:warn]  
[pid 775664:tid 139641145501440]  
[client 182.185.89.141:56110] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  require_once()  
[<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home/duzktilldawn/public_html\\fbapp\\src\\Facebook\\autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/duzktilldawn/public_html/fbapi.php on line 2
```

which results in the following error screen:

[image]

The above code works fine on `localhost`, but it is throwing an error when I upload the website onto a server. Below is the server directory:

[image]

Comment: Please format your code blocks correctly: you need at least four spaces at the beginning of each line to keep the code in a block. Or select it and use the code tool on the toolbar.
We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Included code section and reformatted some grammar.